Sum Time Field in Access
I have three tables created in MS access to track Cycling/gear usage, First table has Activity ID and cycling duration in time (hh:mm:ss), second table has Activity ID and Gear ID, third table has gear ID and Name of the gear, all three tables are connected using relationship.
Im looking to track total gear usage in hours, for example : Gear XX : 135h:45mm:59ss, but access is looking duration field as Date and Time (24 hours format) and the sum result looks like a time format (24 Hours). Duration field is created as Date/Time in table, is it possible to sum time in access? have tried changing the format to hh:nn:ss, i does not seems to work. All tables are created using Excel sheet import and i dont have start or end time to use something like datediff.

How Date/Time data type works
The Date/Time data type can store both dates and times. For time-only values, you can store just the time component (e.g., 09:30:20 or 8:45:20).
Time is store as fraction of a day:
Total Day = 24 hours X 60 Minutes X 60 Seconds = 86400 Seconds
if Time is 6:00:00 then It will be (6 X 60 X 60)/86400 = .25
To get the result as mentioned in the question there will be a function which will convert this decimal value into hours, minutes and seconds.
The Tables will be

tblActivity (ActivityID Number, Duration Date/Time)
tblCyclingByGear (ActivityID Number, GearID Number)
tblGear (GearID Number, GearName ShortText)

Data in tblDuration



ActivityiD
Duration




1
10:12:00 AM


2
1:48:00 PM


3
10:20:00 AM


4
1:00:40 AM


5
2:15:20 AM


7
8:44:40 AM


8
3:10:00 AM



Data in tblCyclingByGear



ActivityID
GearID




1
1


2
1


3
2


4
2


5
2


7
2


8
2



Data in tblGear



GearID
GearName




1
Gear XX


2
Gear YY



Function to calculate hour, minute, second from summation of Date/Time
field
Public Function TotTime(TValue As Double) As String
    Dim TotalMinutes As Long
    Dim Hours As Long
    Dim Minutes As Long
    Dim Seconds As Long
    Dim TimeValue As Date
    Dim bHour As Long
    bHour = 0
    If TValue >= 1 Then
        bHour = Int(TValue)
        bHour = bHour * 24
    End If
   ' Initialize total minutes
    TotalMinutes = 0
    
    TimeValue = TValue
    
    TotalMinutes = TotalMinutes + (Hour(TimeValue) * 60) + Minute(TimeValue) + (Second(TimeValue) / 60)
    
    ' Calculate hours, minutes, and seconds
    Hours = TotalMinutes \ 60
    Minutes = TotalMinutes Mod 60
    Seconds = (TotalMinutes * 60) Mod 60
    Hours = bHour + Hours
    ' Format the result as hh:mm:ss
    TotTime = Format(Hours, "00") & "h:" & Format(Minutes, "00") & "mm:" & Format(Seconds, "00") & "ss"
End Function

Use of this function(TotTime) in MS Access Query
SELECT b.GearID, c.GearName, TotTime(Sum(a.Duration)) AS TotalTime, Sum(a.Duration) AS RawTime
FROM tblActivity AS a, tblCyclingByGear AS b, tblGear AS c
WHERE a.ActivityID = b.ActivityID and b.GearID = c.GearID
GROUP BY b.GearID, c.GearName;

The result of the query



GearID
GearName
TotalTime
RawTime




1
Gear XX
24h:00mm:00ss
1


2
Gear YY
25h:31mm:00ss
1.06296296296296



Implemented query and functions in MS Access 2016

Thanks, never thought calculating time will be complex, Will take this approach.

Consider adjusting your process and database design with a data cleaning  step to parse and calculate that raw value into a decimal value for summation:

Table Design: Avoid storing duration as date/time types since the value is not a true clocked value. If your system/app/API delivers data in that format, store as is in Access' short text or ideally parse the value into numeric type (see #2 or #3).

External Clean/Migrate:

Using whatever language (VBA, Python, R, PHP, Java, PowerShell), clean the raw data by parsing this string value to extract hours, minutes, and seconds. Then calculate the numeric extracts into decimal figures were units are in whatever scale you require (days, hrs, mins, secs). StackOverflow and elsewhere have many solutions to this problem. Save cleaned data set in a popular data format (CSV, XSLX, JSON,  XML) for Access migration.

Migrate the cleaned data to MS Access with programming code making a backend ODBC connection to database or manually with frontend MSAccess.exe GUI data transfer features, saving the numeric duration figures into the number type (as set up in #1).



Internal Clean/Update:

If you choose to bypass the external cleaning step, migrate the raw duration data as is in text/string type.
Run a VBA/SQL routine inside MSAccess.exe to parse, calculate, and store the numeric equivalent (by adding the parsed time components) into the same table using iterative UPDATE calls or bulk INSERT-SELECT via a raw, staging table.


Query Aggregation: Simply run an aggregate query to SUM the numeric field for your end use needs, relaying its units (days, hrs, mins, secs). If needed, extend the decimal total to format for estimated days, hours, minutes, seconds. StackOverflow and elsewhere have many formatting solutions from decimal duration.



Sorry, this is in its core not correct. The Date data type is perfect for storing a time span which here is the source. As Date is based on Double, you can sum such time spans as any other numeric value, thus short cutting your steps 1. to 4. Further, date, time, and time spans should, in Access and most other database engines, never be stored as text, no exceptions; text representation is for display only.

Hmmm...let me wait to hear from OP per the comment that raw data resembles this format: 135h:45mm:59ss. Still though, I have not encountered a need to store or aggregate duration in the colon separator clock format especially beyond the 24-hr range. Yes, all date/times are numeric (usually seconds from epoch of 1/1/1970) and in most DBMSs formatted in ISO as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS. But date/time differences and duration are stored as decimal precision.

Time in the table is stored in hh:nn:ss, the problem is, when adding this column, the output looks like a time format which resembles like 24 hours time format (time of the day). Access is not summing time to give result like 125h:59mm:59 seconds. Never thought summing time be this complex but will take approach shared by @Parfait and Abu Ben Reaz . Will be happy to know if there is any other easier approach.

Will be happy to know if there is any other easier approach ... All you need is a custom format - as shown below.

You'll need a custom function to format the sum of the times, for example:
' Format the count of days, hours, minutes, and seconds of Date1 as
' hours, minutes, and seconds.
' By default, the local time separator is used.
' Optionally, specify a custom time separator.
'
' Example:
'   Date1:      #10:03:01# + #20:01:07#
'   returns:    30:04:08
'
' 2024-11-30. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function FormatHourMinuteSecond( _
    ByVal Date1 As Date, _
    Optional ByVal Separator As String) _
    As String

    Dim TextHour                As String
    Dim TextMinute              As String
    Dim TextSecond              As String
    Dim TextHourMinuteSecond    As String
    
    TextHour = CStr(Fix(Date1) * 24 + Hour(Date1))
    ' Maintain a leading zero for the minute count.
    TextMinute = Right("0" & CStr(Minute(Date1)), 2)
    ' Maintain a leading zero for the second count.
    TextSecond = Right("0" & CStr(Second(Date1)), 2)
    
    If Separator = "" Then
        Separator = FormatSystemTimeSeparator
    End If
    TextHourMinuteSecond = TextHour & Separator & TextMinute & Separator & TextSecond
    
    FormatHourMinuteSecond = TextHourMinuteSecond
  
End Function


' Obtain the system time separator without API calls.
'
' 2021-01-26. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function FormatSystemTimeSeparator() As String

    Dim Separator   As String
    
    Separator = Format(Time, ":")

    FormatSystemTimeSeparator = Separator
    
End Function

Not yet added to my repository at GitHub: VBA.Date.

What is the recommendation to store time field, short text or Time/Date?

That is DateTime. In VBA just Date.
